# Math education questions posted on Math.SE during beta

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720337/how-to-teach-polar-integrals) was posted on Math.SE earlier today. It is pretty clear that it is better suited for Matheducators.SE. Once Matheducators.SE is out private beta, one might expect that this question would be migrated.

**What should be done now, if anything, about such questions posted on Math.SE?**

Comment: Presumably nothing, since we are still in private beta.

Comment: You can extend an invitation to the person (possible in a chat room) and ask them to write it here.